# Вывод из MySql....

Tags: php, html, mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы можно было одну статью добавлять в 2 категории и выводить ее так же в 2 категориях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делается так, делаете табличку со статьями и табличку с категориями. А потом делаете сводную табличку, чтобы реализовать отношение Многие ко многим, в табличке будет id статьи и id категории. Например:

```
id    article_id    category_id
1     3             2
2     3             5
```

Т.е. статья с id=3 принадлежит категориям под id=2 и id=5. Выборку осуществлять нужно через JOIN запрос. Основные тезисы нужные вам - это отношение "Многие ко многим" и "JOIN".